# How to make a DLL for MT4 (using Linux)?

Tags: linux, dll, mt4

I'm using `Linux (Ubuntu)` **64bit** system and need to make a `DLL` for `MetaTrader4`.
I did read lots of things I found about it, but it is very chaotic and confusing. There are many DLLs which are not acceptable for `MT4`. So far it seems that I need: a **32bit** DLL made by using **C++**. There might be other criteria that I don't know. What IDE/compiler (free, if possible) should I use for it on my 64bit Linux system?
I've never made any DLL, so please tell me if there are other important conditions as well that I should know.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create a dll for Linux is using .net core however this will not work for anything MT4 related.

MT4 in all its variations is hooked into specifics system level api on windows and the only way to run anything dealing with it on Linux is to build it for windows and run whatever you write from inside wine.